# How SQL select statements work

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g

I executed the following query and it worked. I want to understand how it works.

```
select 50+2 from employees
```

This works only when the 'employees' table exists. If I mention a non existent table, then it throws an error.

How can such expressions be evaluated for user-defined tables?

Comment: This also works: `select 1,'a' from employees`

Comment: If the dual doesn't work for you, then we need to know more details about your problem and what are you trying to achieve, why do you need to sometimes use existent table and other times not. (what is the situation)?

Comment: Did my answer address your question correctly?

Comment: @Webeng Yes. I wanted to know exactly that, the inner working of the query.

Comment: @MangeshKherdekar Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What MySQL does first is it uses its parser to read the SQL statement and separate it into it's logical parts. A parser (used not only by MySQL but very often in programming) is just a block of code that retrieves raw information, and turns it into something that the program can use.

In the case of MySQL, it will separate

```
SELECT 50+2 FROM employees
```

Into `SELECT 50+2` and `FROM employees`

So lets analyse what each of these two do. The `SELECT` reserved word is used to identify what a user wishes to obtain from the operation. It usually contains a column name. However if you include a string called "*hello*", MySQL interprets that you want to select "*hello*". In this case you want to select a number that is the result of `50+2`.

Now what `FROM employees` does is that it informs MySQL which table you wish to select this information from. It doesn't matter that `50+2` isn't a column or even anything located in the table. MySQL isn't an AI system, and won't ask you questions on why you decided to do that, it just executes commands that are designed following the rules established.

Now MySQL will look through the whole table, and return the selected columns of each row that is consistent with the condition that exists in the `WHERE ...` section of a query. If a query does not have the `WHERE ...` section, it is assumed you want to return all the rows.

The result of your query will then be a column full of the value `52` with the same amount of rows as your table has. If your table has 5 rows, the result will be:

```
52
52
52
52
52
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give expression then just use `SELECT .. Dual`

```
select 50+2 from dual
```

This will also result `52`

Why `select 50+2 from employees` because it is a just a constant value which will be displayed in all the rows of your table, Example the below query will also result constant value 'A' for all the rows

```
Select 'A',col1,col2 from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to reference any existing table and you still want to calculate an expression (note a single expression) you can use the DUAL table in oracle.

```
select 50+2 from dual;

select 1*2*3 from dual;
```

From the oracle doc,

The table named DUAL is a small table in the data dictionary that Oracle Database and user-written programs can reference to guarantee a known result. This table has one column called DUMMY and one row containing the value X.

Comment: Yes I know that. But how does it also work for 'employees' table? What is the use of dual if it works with any existing table? Even `select 50+2` works..

Comment: If your employee table contains say 10 rows, then your output of 52 will be repeated for 10 rows. However if you use the dual table, you will get only one.

Comment: `select 50+2` does not work in Oracle Db, but workd in SQLite